# Insert multiple checkbox values

Tags: sql

I am trying to insert multiple checkbox values in my database with the function insert() of WordPress, but it don't work same when I use a SQL request. Although my table exist I really don't see where is the problem...

```
    <form name="orderform" method="post" >  
    <table id="Tableau" style="border-collapse: collapse;" id="tableauS" border="1"><tr><th>Attributs</th><th>Choix</th></tr></html>
    <?php

    $resultat= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from wp_frm_fields ",ARRAY_N); // lancement de la requete

    foreach ($resultat as $post) {  
        echo '<tr><td>'.$post[2].'</td>';
        echo"<td><center><input type='checkbox' name='choixP' value='".$post[0]."'></center></td>";
    }
    ?>
    <html></tr>

       <input type="submit" name="sub" value="submit">

    </table></form>
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['sub']))  
    {  
    global wpdb;
    $checkbox1=$_POST['choixP'];  
    $chk="";  
    foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
       {  
          $chk = $chk1;  

         $wpdb->insert( 'wp_choix_attributs_liste',
         array('att_id'=>$chk), 
         array(%s) );

       -------- Dont Work too-----------    
          $query = "INSERT INTO wp_choix_attributs_liste (att_id)  VALUES ('".$chk."')";
          mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
       ---------------------------------

       }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it.

```
public function insertionRow($id){

    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_choix_attributs_liste (att_id) VALUES (".$id.");");
}
```

In my html with the checkbox.

```
if(isset($_POST['sub']))  
    {  

        foreach ($_POST['choixP'] as $id) {
            self::insertionRow($id);
        }
    }
```